# Getting new email senders address

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I composed a new email. Before sending this email, I would like (using VBA) to get the senders email address.

I wrote the following example code. When I run this code, the first message box displays the email subject correctly, however the second message box shows nothing (the message box is empty).

```
Sub email_test()

    Dim eSubject As String
    Dim eSender As String

    eSubject = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem.subject
    MsgBox eSubject

    eSubject = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem.SenderEmailAddress
    MsgBox eSender

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

A new mail item doesn't have the Sender* related properties set. They are set right after the message is processed by the transport provider and can be get, for example, from the Sent Items folder. You can handle the `ItemAdd` event of the Items class which comes from the Sent Items folder. Be aware, the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868473.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of the MailItem class can be used to set a Folder object that represents the folder in which a copy of the e-mail message will be saved after being sent. Also the [DeleteAfterSubmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868585.aspx) property can be set, in that case a copy of the mail message is not saved after being sent.

You may be interested in the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff869311.aspx) property which allows to get or set set an `Account` object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

Comment: Thank you Eugene for your help. I also suspected that the sender address is not available prior to sending the email. However, because the selected send account was available on the screen I was hoping there is a shorter way to get the sender's email address without dealing with the senders' accounts.  Now, I will take your advise and try to make it using the SendUsingAccount property and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Using the "SendUsingAccount property" I could get the account name however not the sender's email address that is using this account. Any advise?

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you Dmitry and Eugene for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `MailItem.SendUsingAccount.SmtpAddress`. If `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` is null, you can asssume the default account will be used - the address can be accessed from `Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address`. In case of an Exchange mailbox, use `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AdderssEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress`